# No visible at interface for NSFEtchrequest declares the selector

Tags: xcode, interface, selector, visible

First : sorry for my bad english, i'm french ...

I'm trying to add 2 parsing functions on my Xcode application but i have always the same error :

> No visible at interface for NSFEtchrequest declares the selector

I've added in my .h file the NSFEtchRequest infos :

```
    @interface TableViewControllerRSS : UITableViewController <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        //TableViewControllerRSS *newsRequest;
        NSMutableArray *allNews;
    @private NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel_;
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator_;
        NSManagedObject *managedObject_;
        NSFetchRequest *newsRequest;

@property (nonatomic, retain ) NSFetchRequest *newsRequest;

- (NSString *) dateConverter:(NSString *) dateToConvert;
```

I've added in my .m file :

```
@synthesize newsRequest;
```

I'm trying to change the date format in my RSS request :

before :    `cell.dateArt.text = [uneNews datepub];`

after :     `cell.dateArt.text = [newsRequest dateConverter:[uneNews datepub]];`

But the problem comes just here : when i'm calling the newsRequest dateConverter function.

newsRequest is ViewDidLoad in my .m file :

```
newsRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
[newsRequest setEntity:entity];
```

And the Date COnverter function in my .m file is :

```
- (NSString *) dateConverter:(NSString *) dateToConvert {

    NSDateFormatter *inputFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputFormat setDateFormat:@"eee', 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss '+0000'"];

    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [inputFormat setLocale:usLocale];

    NSDate *formatterDate = [inputFormat dateFromString:dateToConvert];

    NSDateFormatter *outputFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormat setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM/yy"];

    NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
    [outputFormat setLocale:frLocale];

    NSString *newDate = [outputFormat stringFromDate:formatterDate];

    return newDate;

}
```

It's really hard to understand why i always have this error !

Byt the way : thanks every people for reading and eventually wants to help.

Have a nice day
Regards
Manu

Answer (score 0):

NSFetchRequest does not have the "`dateConverter`" method defined as part of that class, unless you added it as part of a category.  And from looking at the "`dateConverter`" code, I don't see why it should be part of your "`NSFetchRequest`" object.

Perhaps you want to define that "`dateConverter`" method on your view controller, or some other object beyond your NSFetchRequest?